# How to programmatically detect if Accessibility event comes from FLAG_SECURE Android app?

Tags: java, android, accessibility, flag-secure

Google has issued this requirement for Android apps, effective November 1, 2022:

"For security and privacy purposes, all apps distributed on Google Play are required to respect the `FLAG_SECURE` declaration of other apps. Meaning, apps must not facilitate or create workarounds to bypass the `FLAG_SECURE` settings in other apps.

"Apps that qualify as an accessibility tool are exempt from this requirement, as long as they do not transmit, save or cache `FLAG_SECURE` protected content for access outside of the user's device."

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12253906#flag_secure_preview

My app collects accessibility data and records it in the cloud, at the user's request. I would like to honor the `FLAG_SECURE` assertions of other apps, but where do I find such data?

In other words, how do I programmatically know in Java if an Accessibility event comes from a `FLAG_SECURE` app?

Comment: Given this is a fairly new requirement, you may be better off asking the Android team directly (https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/report-bugs)

Comment: Asked here: https://support.google.com/android/thread/173317683?hl=en