# Access FLAG_SECURE from an accessibility service

Tags: android, accessibility

Google requires that apps respect the display's FLAG_SECURE. How can we read the FLAG_SECURE value from inside an accessibility service?

GOOGLE'S ANNOUNCEMENT, EFFECTIVE NOV 1, 2022 ([link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12253906#flag_secure_preview)):

> FLAG_SECURE is a display flag declared in an app’s code to indicate
> that its UI contains sensitive data intended to be limited to a secure
> surface while using the app. This flag is designed to prevent the data
> from appearing in screenshots or from being viewed on non-secure
> displays. Developers declare this flag when the app’s content should
> not be broadcast, viewed, or otherwise transmitted outside of the app
> or users’ device.
>
> For security and privacy purposes, all apps distributed on Google Play
> are required to respect the FLAG_SECURE declaration of other apps.
> Meaning, apps must not facilitate or create workarounds to bypass the
> FLAG_SECURE settings in other apps.
>
> Apps that qualify as an Accessibility Tool are exempt from this
> requirement, as long as they do not transmit, save, or cache
> FLAG_SECURE protected content for access outside of the user's device.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73170014. FWIW, I had a quick look when I came across that question the other day, but I couldn't see any obvious way to do it, either. The OP there has an issue posted on the tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240792402.